# What is the difference between initState and a class constructor in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I read the documentation but it is not clear.

It states "[initState is] Called when this object is inserted into the tree."

When a widget is inserted into a tree, it means it has been created, which means the class constructor is called. What is the purpose of init? Isn't the constructor's purpose to initialize the class instance?

Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: Can you link to the documentation you are reading, please? I am guessing it is: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html

Comment: @T.Woody yea that is the one. I read through it more than 5 times. I still don't understand what it means by "depends on the location at which the object was inserted" or "used to configure this widget". Isn't all of that what the class constructor is for?

Comment: I am looking at the direct code to see if I can find it. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/search?q=class+initstate&unscoped_q=class+initstate

Comment: Have you looked at the code directly, yourself, yet? Feedback on where not to look when be helpful :)

Comment: I believe `initState` is derived from (and behaves similar to) after comparing the way the documentation reads: https://apache.github.io/incubator-heron/api/java/com/twitter/heron/api/topology/IStatefulComponent.html#initState-com.twitter.heron.api.state.State-

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The difference is (in the context of creating a `State` object) which has the `initState()` method:

> - `constructor` simply create a new `State` instance
> - `initState()` is called after the object is created and at this point
>   you have access to the `BuildContext` or the `StatefulWidget` to which the `State` is attached to, respectively using the `context` and the `widget` properties. At this point the `State` is already mounted.

Reference `State`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html

Reference `mounted State`: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html

Comment: If you are coming from the python world. Constructor is like the __new__() and initState is like __init__().

Answer (score 17):

In some cases you will need to start an animation or change the state when you create your `Widget`, then is not possible to do that in your constructor because your `Widget` is not inserted in the tree yet.

Example of `AnimationController`

```
    AnimationController _animationController ;

    ...

      @override
        void initState() {
        ... instance the animationController

          _animationController.forward();
          super.initState();
        }
```

Another example, when you receive some params from another `Widget`, let say your `StatefulWidget` has a param named `title` and you want to create a local variable in your State class to handle the state, you will have to do something like this:

```
  class ExampleWidget extends StatefulWidget {

   final String title;

   ExampleWidget({this.title});

  ....


  YourStateClass extends State<ExampleWidget> {

  var localVariable;

  @override
        void initState() {
          localVariable = widget.title;
          super.initState();
        }
```

And now you could use your `localVariable` inside your widget tree to update the state.

Comment: Does this from the twitter API make some sense in the Flutter context, too? https://apache.github.io/incubator-heron/api/java/com/twitter/heron/api/topology/IStatefulComponent.html#initState-com.twitter.heron.api.state.State-

Comment: @diegoveloper Wow, your first explanation was clear as day. I have grasp on it now. However, for the second example....couldn't you just pass  the "title" variable through the constructor of YourStateClass constructor? Such as: YourStateClass(title);

Comment: Yes you can, but you can not call setState inside the constructor

Comment: Last question. If you can access the 'title' property by passing it through the YourStateClass constructor, what is the benefit of doing it via initState() instead?

Comment: @WalterM ok in this case is in reverse , let say you initialized your localVar in your constructor, then you put your localVar in your widget. You will see the value because it was set before your widget was in the tree. 

But if you initiliazed your localVar in initState, and use your localVar in your widget, you won't see the changes until you call setState because your widget was already create before you initialized the value.

Answer (score 3):

> **constructor** is used to create an instance(object).
>
> **initstate** is used to initalize the contents of an already existing object.

For example,

Suppose you open an app having multiple routes / pages. When u open any particular page then an object **A** of its contents is created (with some initial data) which u see on screen.

Now suppose u press a button (which performs a specific task that changes the data) on that particular page. Then **initstate** will be called to initalize the data of object **A** without having u to open the app again from fresh.

**Also**, it must be noted that initstate is called before build and **no context is available** at that moment.

Thats all.