# Error: The instance member ... can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: dart

Why does this code:

```dart
class _SequentialTextPageState {
  String jsonTextPref = 'seqtext';
  int jsonTextSuff = 10;
  String jsonText = jsonTextPref + jsonTextSuff.toString();
}
```

generate these errors?

```
Error: The instance member 'jsonTextPref' can't be accessed in an initializer.

Error: The instance member 'jsonTextSuff' can't be accessed in an initializer.
```

It seems to me that concatenation between `String` and `int` is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use constant expressions as initializers. `x=this.y` is not constant.

Comment: Field initializers do not need to be constant.  For example, this is valid: `import 'dart:math'; var random = Random(); class Foo { int x = random.nextInt(100); }`

Comment: You probably got this mixed up with *default values*, which are required to be constant.

Answer (score 11):

[Dart initializes objects in multiple phases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63319094/).  Initializing members directly ("field initializers") occurs early in object initialization, before `this` becomes valid, so that phase cannot initialize members that depend on other parts of the object.

Dart provides [multiple ways to initialize members](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64548861/), so if one member needs to depend on another, you can initialize it in a later phase by using a different mechanism.  For example, you could do one of:

- Add the `late` keyword to make the dependent member lazily initialized.
- Move initialization of the dependent member into the constructor body.
- In the case of a Flutter `State` subtype, you could initialize the dependent member in its `initState` method, which [in some cases is more appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52066976/).

Note that in some cases you additionally can consider replacing the member *variable* with a read-only *getter* instead.  For example, in your case, perhaps you could use:

```dart
String get jsonText => jsonTextPref + jsonTextSuff.toString();
```

That would be appropriate if `jsonText` should *always* depend on `jsonTextPref` and `jsonTextSuff`, would never need to have an independent value, and if it's acceptable for `jsonText` to return a new object every time it's accessed.

Answer (score 3):

Dart does not allow field initializers to refer to the object itself. Fields must always be fully initialized before any access is given to the object begin created.
The initializers can only access static and top-level variables, not any instance variables on the object itself.

With null safety, you will be allowed to write `late String jsonText = this.something + this.other;`. That field will then not be initialized until it's first read or written, which is necessarily after the object itself has been created.

Answer (score 0):

The error was displayed when I did following:

```
class MyClass {
  String id;
  String[] imagePaths;
}
```

It will mark the String in the line `String id;` as error, but the error is in the next line, it should be `List<String> imagePaths;` instead of `String[] imagePaths;` then the error in the line above also disappears. This can be very confusing if you have a big class and the actual error is many lines underneath the first marked line (talking from experience...)

[image: error image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

```
    class _SequentialTextPageState {

      String jsonTextPref = 'seqtext';
      int jsonTextSuff = 10;
      String jsonText;

     _SequentialTextPageState() : jsonText = jsonTextPref + jsonTextSuff.toString();

    }
```