# Avoid static get definition

Tags: flutter, dart

I created DatasetDatabase to handle some database function calls as following:

```
class DatasetDatabase{
  final Future<Database> database;

  DatasetDatabase(this.database);

  Future loadDatasetTable() async{
    final Database db = await database;
    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> table = await db.query('datasets');
    print(table[0]['dataset']);
    var _datasetList = jsonDecode(table[0]['dataset']).map<Dataset>((e) => Dataset.fromJson(e)).toList();
    return _datasetList;
  }
```

At the same time I have DatabaseService class where I would like to get database and instantiate databases. However, I can't simply pass database as parameter as it can't be accessed in the initializer.

```
class DatabaseService{

  Future<Database> get database async {
    Database _database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'caralgo_database.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE datasets(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dataset TEXT)"
        );
        db.execute(
            "CREATE TABLE unitConfigs(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, unitConfig TEXT)"
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );
    return _database;
  }

  final DatasetDatabase datasetDatabase = DatasetDatabase(database);
  final UnitConfigDatabase unitConfigDatabase = UnitConfigDatabase(database);
}
```

One of the solutions is to make get database static, but I would like to avoid it. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  What problem are you trying to solve?  If you don't want `DatabaseService.database` to be `static`, then just omit the `static` keyword.  Doing so would require clients to construct a `DatabaseService` instance first, however.

Comment: Thank you for your comment I will provide more explanation.

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, your goal is to have a class that has data members initialized with the result of an instance method.  If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/65601214/.