# How to pass parameter functions to widget stored within a map<int, widget>?

Tags: flutter, dart

Ive been trying to work this out for awhile now still getting a hang of flutter as its fairly new to me. Im trying to create an animated menu where once i click on the hamburger icon, it opens the menu and when choosing options within the menu, the screen changes. Im having an issue with passing the `callback` function for each screen to change `menuOpen` to true using `setState`. Since I cannot add the callback function to the screen when adding it to the map, what would i need to do in order to send a function as a parameter to change the `menuOpen` value to open or close the menu. When i add the call back function in the initialisation it says `The instance member 'setState' can't be accessed in an initializer. Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression`

BuildPageStack builds the screen based on the current index of the map.

```
Widget buildPageStack(int place, List<Widget> pageList) {
final deviceWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

return AnimatedPositioned(
  duration: duration,
  top: menuOpen ? deviceWidth * 0.10 : 0.0,
  bottom: 0,
  left: menuOpen ? deviceWidth * 0.40 - (place * 30) : 0.0,
  right: menuOpen ? deviceWidth * -0.130 + (place * 30) : 0.0,
  child: ScaleTransition(
    scale: scaleAnimations[place],
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        if (!mounted)
          return;
        else if (menuOpen) {
          setState(() {
            menuOpen = false;
            animationController.reverse();
          });
        }
      },
      child: AbsorbPointer(
        absorbing: menuOpen,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Material(
                animationDuration: duration,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(menuOpen ? 20.0 : 0.0),
                child: pageList[place]),
            // Container(
            //   color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor.withOpacity(0.5),
            // ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);


}
```

initState method

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: duration);

scaleAnimations = [
  Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.8).animate(animationController),
  Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.7).animate(animationController),
  Tween<double>(begin: 1.0, end: 0.6).animate(animationController),
];
animationController.forward();
adminScreenSnapshot = adminpages.values.toList();
userScreenSnapshot = userpages.values.toList();


}
```

Map initialization and call, if the user is an admin it shows 3 screens, if user it shows 2

```
    Map<int, Widget> adminpages = {
        0: Main_Foster(menuCallback: (){
setState(() {
          menuOpen = true;
          animationController.forward();
        });}),
        1: ProfileScreen(menuCallback: (){
setState(() {
          menuOpen = true;
          animationController.forward();
        });}),
        2: CMS(menuCallback: (){
setState(() {
          menuOpen = true;
          animationController.forward();
        });}),
      };



    Map<int, Widget> userpages = {
        0: Main_Foster(menuCallback: (){
setState(() {
          menuOpen = true;
          animationController.forward();
        });}),
        1: ProfileScreen(menuCallback: () {
setState(() {
          menuOpen = true;
          animationController.forward();
        });}),
      };



 List<Widget> adminScreenSnapshot;
  List<Widget> userScreenSnapshot;

  

List<Widget> finalPageStack() {
    List<Widget> returnStack = [];
    returnStack.add(MenuScreen(
      menuCallback: (selectedIndex) {
        if (widget.isAdmin) {
          setState(() {
            adminScreenSnapshot = adminpages.values.toList();
            final selectedWidget = adminScreenSnapshot.removeAt(selectedIndex);
            adminScreenSnapshot.insert(0, selectedWidget);
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            userScreenSnapshot = userpages.values.toList();

            final selectedWidget = userScreenSnapshot.removeAt(selectedIndex);
            userScreenSnapshot.insert(0, selectedWidget);
          });
        }
      },
    ));
if (widget.isAdmin) {
  adminScreenSnapshot
      .asMap()
      .entries
      .map((screen) => buildPageStack(screen.key, adminScreenSnapshot))
      .toList()
      .reversed
    ..forEach((screen) {
      returnStack.add(screen);
    });
} else {
  userScreenSnapshot
      .asMap()
      .entries
      .map((screen) => buildPageStack(screen.key, userScreenSnapshot))
      .toList()
      .reversed
    ..forEach((screen) {
      returnStack.add(screen);
    });
}

return returnStack;


}
```

FinalPageStack returns the required stack

```
List<Widget> finalPageStack() {
List<Widget> returnStack = [];
returnStack.add(MenuScreen(
  menuCallback: (selectedIndex) {
    if (widget.isAdmin) {
      setState(() {
        adminScreenSnapshot = adminpages.values.toList();
        final selectedWidget = adminScreenSnapshot.removeAt(selectedIndex);
        adminScreenSnapshot.insert(0, selectedWidget);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        userScreenSnapshot = userpages.values.toList();

        final selectedWidget = userScreenSnapshot.removeAt(selectedIndex);
        userScreenSnapshot.insert(0, selectedWidget);
      });
    }
  },
));
if (widget.isAdmin) {
  adminScreenSnapshot
      .asMap()
      .entries
      .map((screen) => buildPageStack(screen.key, adminScreenSnapshot))
      .toList()
      .reversed
    ..forEach((screen) {
      returnStack.add(screen);
    });
} else {
  userScreenSnapshot
      .asMap()
      .entries
      .map((screen) => buildPageStack(screen.key, userScreenSnapshot))
      .toList()
      .reversed
    ..forEach((screen) {
      returnStack.add(screen);
    });
}

return returnStack;


}
```

Comment: See ["The instance member ... can't be accessed in an initializer"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65601214/).

Comment: hey @jamesdlin, The late keyword makes sense but doesnt help in my sistuation, the main issue im facing is im not being able to call the menucall back function within each screen, how would i achieve this?